# use remove() on multiple elements

Tags: javascript

this: `document.getElementsByClassName('warningmessage').remove();` doesn't work if you have multiple warningmessage elements on the page.

How can I just delete all elements with that class? do I have to use a `for each`? isn't there a command to deleteall()?

thanks for your tips!

Comment: are u using any framework? because there is no method remove on dom nodes ?

Comment: `.remove()` is jQuery syntax, if you're using jQuery, you can just do `$('.warningmessage').remove()` to remove all instances.

Comment: no not using jquery. how would I write this for "normal" javascript?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a **`NodeList`**. You have to iterate over this list and remove each node. MDN is a very helpful resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With plain JavaScript you can do this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('warningmessage');
for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
  nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
}
```

So you would first of all get the nodes you are interested in and afterwards iterate over them and remove them from their parents.

Sadly there is no `forEach` method on `NodeList`. However, you could this:

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('warningmessage');
[].forEach.call(nodes, function (node) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
});
```

Comment: Note that this may not get all of the elements if there are nested ones: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/6ZYkk/

Comment: is that needed? i would actually say, that having elements with the same classname nested is kinda strange. however I can see some usecase.

Comment: It's probably not needed; OP didn't say one way or the other. I was just pointing out a possible edge case that may not work. (Note that theintersect's answer _will_ cover this.)

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a loop. The below code shows how you write in "normal" javascript.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('warningmessage'),
    element;
while (element = elements[0]) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

***[The working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/WCu3a/)***
​

Comment: Will this work if there are nested elements such that parent _and_ (grand)child(ren) have that class?

Comment: I was kind of thinking of the situation where a parent happened to be removed before its child(ren): wouldn't that take the child(ren) with it? Or not? If it does, that would mess up the loop counter...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, you are right! `elements` will change dynamically. I updated my answer :)

Comment: Cool. +1 for the new version.

Comment: +1. This version actually works, unlike the accepted answer =p

Answer (score 3):

This would be super easier using JQuery:

```
$('.warningmessage').remove();
```

But it's not that hard when you do it without. getElementsByClassName can return a nodelist of items. So you'll just have to loop through the list and remove each item:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("warningmessage");
for(var i = list.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var n = list[i];
    n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
}
```

Comment: Then you'll have to use the solution without JQuery, which is just a simple loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
var elms= document.getElementsByClassName('warningmessage');
while(elms.length>0){
   for(var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++){
      elms[i].parentNode.removeChild(elms[i]);
   }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gBwjA/

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before and I end up in this algorithm.

```
function removeElement(target) {
    if(target.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
        for(i=0; i<target.length; i++) {
            removeElement(target[i]);
        }
    } else {
        target.parentNode.removeChild(target);  
    }
}
```

and then you call the function like this:

```
removeElement(document.getElementById('the-id'));
```

or if you want to remove an HTML collection of elements then you call the function in this way:

```
removeElement(document.getElementsByTagName('tag-name'));
```