# Remove element by tag name

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [use remove() on multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489364/use-remove-on-multiple-elements)

I am trying to remove all elements that have a tag name of "label". I have the following code. It works to some degree, but it only removes 1 label. The other 5 still remain. How can I change the code to remove all "label" tags?

```
element = document.getElementsByTagName("label");
for (index = 0; index < element.length; index++) {
    element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("label"), index;

for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
}
```

Comment: I've reversed the counter because if you increase it, it will never stop :-)

Comment: @Alfonso Thanks for the edit, that's what I actually meant of course. :)

Answer (score 37):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByTagName()` returns a `NodeList`, not an `Array`. The content, and therefore length, of a `NodeList` is updated when you remove an element from the DOM that's in the `NodeList`. So when you remove the first element, the `NodeList` gets shorter and a *new* first element occupies `index` 0. Updating `index` in the loop therefore makes you miss at least one element, possibly more depending on the length of the result.

Try something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('label')
while (elements[0]) elements[0].parentNode.removeChild(elements[0])
```

Comment: +1 Nicely explained. And shorter than a reverse loop, too.

Comment: Not all NodeList are updated live :)

Comment: Just for kicks: `while (elem = elements.pop()) { elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); }` (you should, of course, declare `elem` beforehand)

Comment: @florian-margaine do you have good reference you could link to for that fact?

Comment: @seliopou: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 4):

When you remove the nodes from a document, the list of nodes that you just obtained from `getElementsByTagName()` gets updated too to avoid lingering references, so you should just keep removing the first node until none remain.

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("label");

for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i != len; ++i) {
    nodes[0].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[0]);
}
```

Here, the value of `nodes.length` is cached; otherwise it would keep decreasing and you end up only removing half :)

Answer (score 2):

The "problem" is that `.getElementsByTagName()` returns a *Live NodeList*. Hence, when you remove the head (first) entry, the tail fills up and *moves* to the left, so to speak.

Its not a real *Javascript Array* where this would work as expected. To create such a *frozen Array* we can go like

```
var element = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("label"),0); 

for (var index = 0, len = element.length; index < len; index++) {
    element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use jQuery? Then it's simply

```
$("label").remove();
```