# Remove HTML h1 empty tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can i remove `h1` empty tag using JavaScript only?

```
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<p>adadasdasdasdsaddasd</p>


<h1></h1>
<p>adadasdasdasdsaddasd</p>

<h1></h1>
<p>adadasdasdasdsaddasd</p>

<h1></h1>
<p>adadasdasdasdsaddasd</p>
```

Comment: this could be helpful [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003606/remove-element-by-tag-name

Comment: You can also use `h1:empty {display: none;}` if you don't want to remove the elements literally from the DOM

Answer (score 1):

You can

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('h1'), //find all h1
    el;
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    el = els[i];
    //if there is no first child 
    if (!el.firstChild) {
        //remove the node
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el)
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2nwqaxrz/)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var hOne = document.getElementsByTagName('h1'),
   current;

  for(var i = hOne.length; i--;) {
   current = hOne[i];
   if(!current.innerHTML.trim()) {
    current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
   }
  }

  alert(document.body.innerHTML);
 </script>

Comment: Please let me know if this is i am doing correct,. --<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  
   <script type="text/javascript">
  var hOne = document.getElementsByTagName('h1'),
   current;

  for(var i = hOne.length; i--;) {
   current = hOne[i];
   if(!current.innerHTML.trim()) {
    current.parentNode.removeChild(current);
   }
  }

  alert(document.body.innerHTML);
 </script>

Comment: the problem is you have kept the script in header... you need to use onload event

Comment: Thanks After one more try its works ... Thanks  a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

if you use jquery try this :

```
  $('h1').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(':empty')){
         $(this).remove()
       }
    });
```

for more info see http://api.jquery.com/is/ and http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Also try this with css empty tags:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOOmOj

```
h1:empty { background: #ccc; display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution using javascript:

```
while (!document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].remove()) {}
```

Yes, I know, as soon as there are no more `h1` left, the loop ends by an

```
TypeError: ... is undefined`.
```

But hey, it *is* **simple**.