# Hide/Show all images toggle button

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create a toogle button HIDE/SHOW. When I press it, all images on website must dissapear, and also when I press it again, all images must appear again.

Comment: is `jquery` allowed here??

Comment: @ozil: not necessary, in pure CSS it's one line function.

Answer (score 3):

Here is short code sample.

When the button is clicked, check if `body` has `class="hide"` or not and add/remove this class. Then in CSS are images inside a body with `class="hide"` hidden.

```
<style>
    .hide img {display: none}
</style>

<p>p</p>
<p>abc</p>
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
<button id="button">SHOW/HIDE</button>

<script>
    var button = document.getElementById('button');
    var body = document.body;

    button.onclick = function() {
        body.className = body.className == 'hide' ? '' : 'hide';
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ajr0e01/

It's pure JS solution without frameworks, without iterations over all images in website. It should be (one of) the fastest.

Comment: A really nice way to do it in pure **JavaScript**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it and you help me a lot. All of you guyz!

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="button" value="Toggle images" onclick="$('img').toggle();" />
```

That's it! :-)

**EDIT**
I didn't really notice that maybe you didn't want the solution in jQuery. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this easily by using JQuery :

```
<input id='myinput'>Click to Toggle </input>

var status = "show";

$("#myinput").Click(function() {
    if (status == "show") {
        $('img').hide();
        status = "hide";
    } else {
        $('img').show();
        status = "show";
    }
});
```

With JQUERY Toggle (taking advice from the comments): 
 [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hh0q41xs/1/)

```
    $(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("img").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't toggle images, this just hides them.

Comment: Yes I missed *toggle*. Its a better way to do it. Saves us from the burden of saving the state.

Comment: If you're gonna use jQuery then why not use the toggle() function?

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>


<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").toggle();
    });
});
```

LINK : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/hh0q41xs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageVisible = true;

var btn = document.getElementById('your_button_id');

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    if (imageVisible) {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
            images[i].style.display = 'none'
        imageVisible = false;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
            images[i].style.display = 'inline'
        imageVisible = true;
    }
});
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/taczevum/1/)

Comment: I'd say this solution is spot on when it comes to pure JS. Neat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version - taken from this answer: [Remove element by tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003606/remove-element-by-tag-name)

```
<img src="#" height="100" width="100" />
<br>
<img src="#" height="100" width="100" />
<br>
<button onclick="DeleteImages()">Delete all images</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DeleteImages(){
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (index = element.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
        }
    }
</script>
```