# How to delete specified children?

Tags: javascript, html, removechild

```html
<body>
  <p>dfg</p>
  <h1>yoyo</h1>
  <h1>yoyo2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>somo</li>
   </ul>
 </body>
```

For example I want to delete only h1 from body. The other children should stay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element by id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387427/remove-element-by-id)

Comment: Thanks for this question. I was just out to dinner with my teenage son and wondering the same thing. :)

Comment: What kind of a father would delete his children?! And without even naming them... That's so sad 

Comment: It's actually more accurately a duplicate of [**remove element by tag name**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14003606/2902660)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get an HTMLCollection (not an array) of the h1 tags, which is *live*.

When an element is removed, the elements update their indexes accordingly which means that you have to remove each element from the last position to the first.

Javascript solution:

```
var h1Elems = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');

for(var i = h1Elems.length - 1;  i >= 0;  i--){
  h1Elems[i].parentElement.removeChild(h1Elems[i]);
}
```

[See this code working in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7LLpr40L/)

Comment: It would be simpler to just say `while (h1Elems.length) h1Elems[0].remove();`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a CSS selector.

You can do it using jQuery or VanillaJS. For instance, here is my code for VanillaJS.

```
var headers = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
headers.forEach(function(h) { h.remove(); });
```

This will effectively remove the headers from the DOM.

Comment: Yes, assuming you are in an environment in which `forEach` is defined on the result of `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: In the case you don't have access to it, you can use jQuery (for example) to do that for you or you can use a polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

We can create our own fn to remove node by tag for usability. please review this one:

```js
function rem(tag) {
  var h = document.querySelectorAll(tag); //return NodeList not array    
  [].forEach.call(h,function(elm) {            
      elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
  });
}

//passing tag to remove
rem('p');
```

```html
<body>
  <p>dfg</p>
  <h1>yoyo</h1>
  <h1>yoyo2</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>somo</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Why is the `if (h.parentNode` check necessary? And are you sure `forEach` will work on the result from `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo, I tried to so many times to get `if(h.parentNode)` return `false` but failed. I just edited my answer including fixing how we should handle NodeList return by `querySelectorAll`