# How to remove anchor tag '<a></a>' using javascript

Tags: html, css

How to remove anchor tag '' in java script?
When I inspected the page, below is the screenshot of what I got
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="dropdownm1-content">
<a href="http://www.cotton.com/shop/"id="view_link"><b>SHOP ALL</b></a>
<b>SHOP BY CATEGORY</b>
<p class="mn_category">
```

Comment: need to see your javascript code

Comment: Some code is adding separators etc to your code. Perhaps some plugin to create a dropdown from your divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove element by tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14003606/remove-element-by-tag-name)

Comment: @Pac0 - more likely an X/Y problem

Comment: You have said how to remove in JavaScript. How can one say without seeing it?

Comment: in console inspect i put this code $0.style.display = "none" this is work, but how to put that code in my web?

Comment: @Pac0 You reference a question that also has been marked a duplicate itself.

Comment: @connexo I don't think this is an issue. To me, the question I referenced seemed to match the actual question better. But in essence, the "top" duplicate target answers it too. Feel free to indicate the top one as potential duplicate.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.dropdownm1-content .text-main a:first-child').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Just get the Element by using the ID of it and then remove it with the remove() function. Like so:

```
var removeanchor = getElementById('YOURANCHORTAGID');
removeanchor.remove();
```

or without creating a variable:

```
getElementById('YOURANCHORTAGID').remove();
```

(replace YOURANCHORTAGID with the id of your anchortag). If you want to trigger this after an action just create a function and trigger it with the action you want :).

for further information check the mdn docs: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Answer (score 0):

You may should add some more information to your question for a more precise answer. However, for the time being this may helps you out.
If you try to use it, pay attention to the fact, that I only adressed the first Element with the class 'text_main' and only the first of its children with 'a' Tag. You may need to change this, according to your code.

```js
// Removing a specified element without having to specify its parent node
container = document.getElementByClass("text_main")[0];
var node = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
if (node.parentNode) {
  node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
}
```

Further information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild

Answer (score 0):

For that specific link you showed:

```
document.querySelector('.dropdownm1-content .text-main a:first-child').remove()
```

**Though I'd highly recommend curing the sickness, not the symptom.**